# bitwise operation techinques for unpacking and packing values into one int

Tags: c, macros, bit-manipulation

### Finally understood what was wrong. It was my brain

Probably the worst embarrassment of the year...a comment `do you understand how binary operators work?` was right.

```
A >> 2 #shifts the value of A to right by 2 bits
```

And all this time, for years, I thought 2 is shifted by the value of A in the case above!!

Sorry guys for this silly question and thank you for correcting my idiocy and your tolerance and kindness are much appreciated.

## Original post

I'm trying to understand how a portion of a DIY keyboard firmware works.The firmware is called qmk: https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware

I'm not exactly certain but the code is in a c variant called AVR c.

### What the code does?

The C macro changes keyboard layer when held, like a function key does, and send a hid usage id to pc when quickly tapped.

### The code

The initial value for layer is a decimal between 1 to 32.
kc is any one of the hid usage ids.

```
#define QK_LAYER_TAP          = 0x4000
#define LT(layer, kc) (kc | QK_LAYER_TAP | ((layer & 0xF) << 8))
#define ACTION_LAYER_TAP_KEY(layer, key) ACTION_LAYER_TAP((layer), (key))
#define ACTION_LAYER_TAP(layer, key)  (ACT_LAYER_TAP<<12 | (layer)<<8 | (key))
```

In another file within a loop, the below is fired when user presses a key to which maybe `LT(2,KC_A)` is bound.

```
case QK_LAYER_TAP ... QK_LAYER_TAP_MAX:
    action.code = ACTION_LAYER_TAP_KEY((keycode >> 0x8) & 0xF, keycode & 0xFF);
    break;
```

### What happens

So, in the case of `LT(2,KC_A)`, this macro `#define LT(layer, kc) (kc | QK_LAYER_TAP | ((layer & 0xF) << 8))` yields  `04 | 0x4000 | ((2 & 0xf) << 8)`.

```
KC_A -> 101
0x8 -> 00001000
0xf -> 00001111
0x4000->100000000000000
2&0xf -> 00000010
((2&0xf)<<8) -> 1000000000
```

The firmware detects 0x4000 bit mask and calls the above `case QK_LAYER_TAP`, then some magic number keycode appears which originates from LT macro.

For `LT(2,04)` keycode yields 2 for `(keycode >> 0x8) & 0xF`, and keycode yields 4 for `keycode & 0xff`.

### The question(Edited since no one understood me)

keycode contains a bit sequence in int16 from the first and the second parameters of the LT macro call.

- The first parameter is an number ranging from 0 to 36 which is of course a user defined value.
- The second parameter is any one of hid usage ids which ranges from 0 to 231.

Since evaluating the expression `keycode & 0xff` yields the hid usage id passed to LT, it is clear keycode contains the second parameter of LT in the first 8 bits.

To this point everything is clear. But....

`(keycode >> 0x8) & 0xF` yields the first parameter of TL.

- 0x8 is `00001000`
- shift the above to right by 4 `4 >> 0x8` results in zero...

  <strike>Since the lower bits of keycode is in use, only upper 8 bits can modified and hid usage id can be a big number and the expected output for the above expression is a positive number!

  The only way seems `some negative value >> 0x8` and that can be done, but I cannot wrap my head around how I can manipulate the value of `(keycode >> 0x8) & 0xF` without touching the lower 8bits.</strike>

Comment: We are not an "explain this code I found somewhere online" site. If something not clear, ask the author.

Comment: This is unclear to me. Are you asking how the bit wise operators, i.e `|` `&` `>>` `<<`, works?

Comment: I read the question twice and I still don't understand what you're asking. Doesn't the "what happens" section explain what happens? What does *"how to generate a bit sequence like this"* mean? Which bit sequence? It seems that the `keycode` contains "layer information" in the lower nibble of the high byte (hence `(keycode >> 8) & 0xF`), and "key information" in the lower byte (masked with `0xFF` to remove the layer information).

Comment: Do you understand the basics of how C bitwise operations work? Just write the numbers in binary and perform the operations and you'll see how it works.

Comment: @Groo LT(2,04) macro combines a bunch of values into 16bits int. Then that combined value somehow used to generate a variable keycode which yields 2 for `(keycode >> 0x8) & 0xF`, 4 for `keycode & 0xff`. And I don't understand how key code is computed or how could a single variable be used like that, though it could be something very basic be for people well versed with bitwise operation...

Comment: The code basically only replaces `QK_LAYER_TAP` with `ACT_LAYER_TAP`. Yes, `LT(layer, key)` sets the uppermost nibble to `QK_LAYER_TAP`. The code in the `case` statement then removes `QK_LAYER_TAP` and calls `ACTION_LAYER_TAP_KEY(layer, key)` which is the same thing as `LT` but uses a different constant and is shuffled a bit.

Comment: @Groo Ya, I could track things to that point. But layer and key are combined into a single variable keycode for some reason and how to decode it into the original values are not something I'm used to, or at least the first method,  `(keycode >> 0x8) & 0xF` and `keycode & 0xff`. The later is easy but how can it work with the earlier `(keycode >> 0x8) & 0xF`?  I guess it's to basic and stupid question but can you please give me a pointer like what to read or what keyword to search for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with firmware which is driving hardware.  Shifting some bits and ORing them with others is creating the contents of a hardware register, in this case apparently a hardware configuration register.

It needs to put in bit flags, shift values, etc., to match the format of the register, which contains a lot of information, each piece one or more bits long, at specific locations.

To understand exactly what this is doing you would need to know specifics about the hw/sw interface, which may not be forthcoming.

Now, to your specific question.  You wrote:

> shift the above to right by 4 `4 >> 0x8` results in zero...

This is shifting keycode 8 bits to the right, not shifting 8 by keycode bits.
Since the first 8 bits are one value, which you have explained, this is extracting what is coded into the higher bits.

For example:

If your two parameters are 5 (to be encoded into the high part) and 4 (to be encoded into the low word):

lower word, in binary
00000100

higher word, in binary
00000101

Together:
0000010100000100

So bitwise & with 0xFF will give you 4
Shifting the value 8 bits to the right will give you 5.

Also, these are most likely *unsigned* integers.  Signed integers are not generally used for this kind of work.

Comment: Sorry for the silly post and really thank you for your answer. No wonder why others could not answer my question, 1+1 is 2 and explaining why is hard...

Comment: Not a silly post; hey, I worked with this stuff about daily for like 15 years (they hired me even though I made a silly mistake when they tested me during my interview.  I got better at it :-)  Most programmers never have to deal with these things.  Until you get it, it looks like Greek (if you're not Greek) or Chinese (if you're Greek? :-)  )

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you should rewrite this as a single succinct question. ..But, it sounds like what you meant to ask is: "what is this code doing". I'll try to explain.

your case statement is executing this line: `action.code = ACTION_LAYER_TAP_KEY((keycode >> 0x8) & 0xF, keycode & 0xFF);`

`ACTION_LAYER_TAP_KEY` takes 2 arguments. Lets look at them individually.

The first is `(keycode >> 0x8) & 0xF`, what this does is take the `keycode` and bit shift it 8 places to the right (bits that go off the end are lost). The result is then and-ed (bitwise) with `0xF` (`00001111`). This has the effect of discarding everything but but the first 4 bits.

The second is `keycode & 0xFF`. What this does is discard everything except the first 8 bits of keycode. So now the arguments are keycode bits 8-11 and keycode bits 0-7.

Ok, now what does `ACTION_LAYER_TAP_KEY` do with this data?

`#define ACTION_LAYER_TAP_KEY(layer, key) ACTION_LAYER_TAP((layer), (key))`

Ok, it calls `ACTION_LAYER_TAP` with the same arguments. Now lets look at that.

`ACTION_LAYER_TAP(layer, key)  (ACT_LAYER_TAP<<12 | (layer)<<8 | (key))`

First it takes `ACT_LAYER_TAP`, which is probably a constant and bit shifts it by 12 to the left. Then it does the same to `layer` except by 8, then it takes these two and `key` and or's them (bitwise). The result will be `<ACT_LAYER_TAP><layer><key>` packed into the integer. Layer can have values 0-15, and key can have values 0-255.

Refering back to the above, we can see that `<layer>` is really just bits 8-11 of keycode. and key is bits 0-7 of keycode. So what we really end up with is `<ACT_LAYER_TAP><first 12 bits of keycode>` packed into an integer.